# Renaming XCodeProject gives error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I created a xcodeproject named ABC.xcodeproj and successfully build it. Later i have renamed it to XYZ.xcodeproj. Bt while building it shows error like this-

> i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.2.1: /Volumes/Partition 2/Client/ABC/ABC_Prefix.pch: No such file or directory
>
> i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.2.1: warning: '-x objective-c-header' after last input file has no effect
>
> i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.2.1: no input files

I have renamed target, product, executable and also pch file to XYZ. I also checked double by renaming XYZ_Prefix.pch to ABC_Prefix.pch, but no success.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what exactly you want to do.... Do you want to change the display name of the project on the home screen of the iphone?

Comment: Atul, actually i want to rename whole project, including target,executables,info.plist, appDelegate..whole everything except classes and nibs

Comment: Take note when renaming .m and .h files e.g. the appDelegate, XCode has a better way of renaming class files, go to .h and highlight the name e.g. @interface MyAppDelegate , highlight MyAppDelegate then right click or Go to Edit Menu -> Refactor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you renamed the project simply in the filesystem then you did it wrong, rename it again to the original name and open it in XCode, then go to Project -> Rename... and it will correctly rename your project for you (including all the related files).

If your XCode doesn't have this rename function, maybe you can try the old way of manually renaming files and contents, maybe this [link](http://aplus.rs/programming/how-to-rename-project-in-xcode-3x/) will help.

Comment: Manny, in xcodeproject under project menu-tab no renaming option is there. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Product Name search there and change your Product Name

Comment: I'm using the XCode 3.2.4, what version are you using?

Comment: Mine is 3.1.4 for leopard 10.5.8

Comment: Okay, see my update.  Based from the link I gave, you still need to delete the build folder, open the contents of .xcodeproj which is actually a folder, then open project.pbxproj with text editor and rename all occurrences of old name to new name, then open all xib files with text editor and do the same, then open it with xCode and clean all target, and you should be set.  Take note that the pch file should also be renamed (I believe you reverted it)

Comment: Or if it's not much of a trouble, update to the latest XCode which gives the easy way of renaming projects.